# Docker commands are running in console with Jenkins user but not within the pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins

Docker commands are running in console with Jenkins user but not within the pipeline

I have a Jenkins inside ubuntu 14.04, I installed Docker as a service and I added Jenkins user to the docker group with the command sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins, everything was fine, I ran docker commands in the console but when I run docker commands within a pipeline it says:
`Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.38/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=csxn4dmmf5v1ex0s7f83bhr62&shmsize=0&t=192.168.0.1%3A5000%2Fgo-app%3A14&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`

when I run `id` in concole it says:
uid=107(jenkins) gid=113(jenkins) groups=113(jenkins),998(docker)
and it is completely fine but when i run `id` whitin a pipeline it says
uid=107(jenkins) gid=113(jenkins) groups=113(jenkins)

Comment: When you say "I added Jenkins user to the docker group", do you mean you did this inside the Dockerfile that defines the image, or did you exec into the running container and do this?

Comment: Hi John, im running both services (docker and jenkins) as services, and when I say "I added JEnkins user to the docker group" it means that I ran ```usermod -a -G docker jenkins```

Comment: So do you have Jenkins & Docker running inside an Ubuntu VM, or are you trying to run Jenkins & Docker inside an Ubuntu base container?  If it's the former, have you tried restarting the Jenkins process?

Comment: I'm running both services inside an Ubuntu VM, and yes, I already tried to restart everythin (services and even the VM), the weird thing is that if I run the docker commands connecting to the VM with SSH, it works, but if I run the same command whitin a pipeline, the error appears.